# Working with giant numbers in PHP

Tags: php, math, package, largenumber

Morning Guys. 
I'm looking for a way/extension, so that I can calculate FAST with really big numbers in PHP, e.g. multiplication with 50-digit numbers.

And please don't tell me, I shall use BC Math or GMP.
They were my second idea, 
but both are so useless, when the result has more than 38 digits both just returning "false".

I allready tried writing an own calculation function, which is actually working, but I believe it's a bit to slow.
It's saving every digit of a number in an array, and calcs like I learned it in Elementary school.

it's working perfect only when the incoming numbers are arrays too.
cause elseway the computer will break them before he can save them.

Is there a way to make my function a bit faster, or does there exist a lib which really calcs with bignumbers?

```
function multiplicate($A, $B)
{
    if (!is_array($A))
    {
        $A = preg_split("//", strval($A), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }
    if (!is_array($B)) 
    {
        $B = preg_split("//", strval($B), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }

    if ( $A[0]=='-') 
    {
        array_splice($A, 0, 1);
        $negA=-1;
    }
    else 
    {
        $negA=1;
    };
    if ( $B[0]=='-') 
    {
        array_splice($B, 0, 1);
        $negB=-1;
    }
    else 
    {
        $negB=1;
    };

    $l = 0;
    $m = 0;
    $Erg[0] = 0;

    for ( $i=0; $i < count($A); $i++) 
    {
        for ( $j=0; $j < count($B); $j++) 
        {
            $ZwErg = preg_split("//", strval($A[$i]*$B[$j]), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);      
            if ($i==0&&$j==0&&count($ZwErg)==2) 
            {
                $l = 1;
            }
            if (count($ZwErg)==2)
            {
                $m = -1;
            }
            for ( $k=0; $k < count($ZwErg); $k++) 
            {
                $s = $i + $j + $l + $m + 1;
                if (isset($Erg[$s])) 
                {
                    $Erg[$s] = intval($Erg[$s]) + intval($ZwErg[$k]);

                    for ( $n=$s; $n >= 0; $n--)
                    {
                        if (intval($Erg[$n])>9) 
                        {
                            $Erg[$n-1] = intval($Erg[$n-1]) + 1 ;
                            $Erg[$n] = intval($Erg[$n] - 10);
                        }
                     };
                }
                else
                {
                    $Erg[$s] = $ZwErg[$k];
                }
                $m = 0;
            }
        }           
    }
    if ($Erg[0]==0) 
    {
        array_splice($Erg,0,1);
    }

    if ($negA*$negB==-1) 
    {
        array_splice($Erg,0,0,"-"); 
    }
    //$Erg = implode("", $Erg);
    return $Erg;
}
```

.

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

require'mathlab.php';

$a=array(1,2,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,6,4,2,5,6,1,2,3,9,5,2,6,7,9,0,4,6,3,9,5,2,6,7,9,0,4,6,7,1,2,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,6,4,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,3,8,1,5,2,8,1,4,0,7,1,2,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,6,4,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,3,8,1,5,2,8,1,4,0,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,6,4,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,7,8,9,0); // 100-digits

$b=array(3,9,5,2,6,7,9,0,4,6,7,1,2,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,3,9,5,2,6,7,9,3,9,5,2,6,7,9,0,4,6,7,1,2,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,6,4,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,3,8,1,5,2,8,1,4,0,0,4,6,7,1,2,3,4,3,1,0,9,5,8,7,6,4,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,3,8,1,5,2,8,1,4,0,6,4,2,5,6,7,8,9,0,3,8,1,5,2,8,1,4,0); // 100-digits

$a2=123431095876425612395267904639526790467123431095876425678903815281407123431095876425678903815281403431095876425678907890;

$b2=395267904671234310958739526793952679046712343109587642567890381528140046712343109587642567890381528140642567890381528140;

$d=multiplicate($a, $b);

$time_end = microtime(true);

$time = $time_end - $time_start;

$erg= implode("", $d);

echo $erg;  // returns 48788350638348981414888625840026024706504222587793349182466850334644805413224925671434030836485835140547446449665876539897036829747577622276768694829991017552834308659985345098432904112370002027411248553582029194707890154740774064503024600

echo $time; // returns 0.75173783302307

$erg3=bcmul($a2, $b2);

$erg4=bcmul(123431095876425612395267904639526790467123431095876425678903815281407123431095876425678903815281403431095876425678907890, 395267904671234310958739526793952679046712343109587642567890381528140046712343109587642567890381528140642567890381528140);

$erg2=gmp_mul($a2, $b2);

$erg5=gmp_mul(123431095876425612395267904639526790467123431095876425678903815281407123431095876425678903815281403431095876425678907890, 395267904671234310958739526793952679046712343109587642567890381528140046712343109587642567890381528140642567890381528140);


echo gmp_strval($erg2); // returns 0

echo gmp_strval($erg5); // returns 0

echo $erg3; // returns 0

echo $erg4; // returns 0
```

Comment: If you really require such precision have you considered using a different language?  You are I would say looking for a big number library,  such as this in C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class  or check out this post for some more agnostic approaches http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131107/handling-extremely-large-numbers-in-a-language-which-cant .  PHP is unlikely to be your best choice for this.

Comment: What is wrong with your bcmath? http://3v4l.org/Ybf1a

Comment: @Gavin hmm. I wanted to start learning java or C# this month anyway, so yeah I believe I should choose C#. But in that second post they aren't even as far as I'm xD I allready wrote add, sub, and multi(this here), who are allready working, and I just need some optimisation.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you'd even consider your own implementation for such a function. Serious mathematical brainiacs created and perfected (somewhat) algorithms that are readily available to you and me, and you think you can redo their work with an array or two?

Comment: @RainFromHeaven: One Reason that I wanted to write it myself is that I wanted too understand it, and as training of course. And where can I find these perfect algorithms? as I allready wrote a few times, bc math and GMP aren't working... And I couldn't find an other working code for that Problem...

Comment: To learn, I would recommend that you reverse engineer an existing solution, instead of creating your own. For example, check out http://gmplib.org/ and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java. You should also google keywords such as 'arbitrary precision arithmetic'

Comment: hmm... for me it's easier to learn by doing/trying, than seeing such a huge code and read through all of it... And I allready know how the computer saves numbers in IEEE-754-format and stuff like that...

Comment: What if you put quotes around those strings of digits? $a2="123... "

Comment: @Joni: this is... so ashaming... because it worked... thanks Joni... Why is it always something that simple, I can't see... *taking my head and smashing it on the desk* Ooh and if you would wrote that as answer too, I would give you "best Answer" of course

Comment: The fact that bcmul takes strings as parameters is apparent in the answer, see the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bcmath` or `GMP`.

For example,

```
echo bcmul("123431095876425612395267904639526790467123431095876425678903815281407123431095876425678903815281403431095876425678907890",
           "395267904671234310958739526793952679046712343109587642567890381528140046712343109587642567890381528140642567890381528140");
```

Gives the output:

48788350638348981414888625840026024706504222587793349182466850334644805413224925671434030836485835140547446449665876539897036829747577622276768694829991017552834308659985345098432904112370002027411248553582029194707890154740774064503024600

Comment: Didn't I just wrote that bcmath and GMP aren't options. Even so that I'm intrested why it's working for you, but sadly they won't work for me, as I allready wrote... but I will add something more seeable...

Comment: If `bcmath` is not working on your system, maybe it would be more fruitful to find out why and fix it, rather than implement an arbitrary precision math library yourself.

Comment: that's kinda true... but how shall I find out that Problem?